# User interests vs user's interests

Tags: possessives

I need to write a sentence in my thesis relative to the preference of the user for a specific topic.
The phrase is:

> We also enhance our system with additional features such as user interests.

Is it correct to refer to "user interests" or "user's interests"?

Generally, I have some doubts with the expressions like "user interests" or "user's interests" or "interests of the user". I do not know what is the general rule, when I can use one or the others.

Comment: There are several questions on this site that ask about this same difference: that between an adjective and a possessive noun. Unfortunately I cannot recall the others or I would link to them, because they almost certainly have additional helpful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In computer software development, everything adheres to a model that helps you understand what the program needs to do. It sounds like your model includes a user and a system. The user uses the system to do something.

Because of this model being simplified and general, it doesn't really make sense to keep track of ownership, I suppose. You're not talking about a specific user, you're using this model to describe how the system responds to every user that will ever use it. The input from every single user is going to be interpreted generally as "user input", that is, input from any user, not input belonging to a specific user.

This is a similar thing. User interests are interests from any user, not belonging to a certain user. The possessive doesn't really make sense from the perspective of software design.

That said, right now your sentence sounds like the enhancing feature is that now the users will have interests. You should say that the feature is "handling" or "taking into account" user interests.